# Foreign banking transfers

Tags: banking, foreign

I have been communicating with a woman who is active duty (Marine) in Syria for several weeks now.  She has been chatting with me trough Hangouts.
Then just a week ago she asked if I could help her with something.  She said her late father was an engineer.  He had done a large project for an oil and gas company in the Ukraine. She was contacted by the company that they would pay here as she is next of kin. She because she has limited internet access in her location, would I help.  I said I will try.  She then forwarded an mail as follows:

Hello Ms. Janet,
   We sent you and the other family an email about the money we owe your parents. We apologize for owing but that was because of the crisis that hit our company at a time we could do nothing about it and it has taken us years to fix. Now we are paying off every debt. We would have asked you to come over to claim the money but because of the global epidemic and the movement ban placed on all the countries to avoid the spread of the COVID-19 we decided to make it easier as we have limited time. The other family already got their money and now you have got just 24 hours to open an account  or have a close family who you trust  to open an account with Stand Crest bank with their website standcrest.com and forward us the account details to enable us wire the money into the account.

Best Regards,
Anastasia Grams
Head of Department
Account support Manager
Naftogaz oil and gas company

I then contacted the company and this was the email reply from the bank after I registered:

Hello Mr. Frederick,
   Your account is set up already and you can begin your several transactions in the account. But optionally to avoid any glitches in future and since you are expecting a huge sum of money into the account, we advice you to make a cash deposit of $2,000 and above to kick start the account.

We thank you for trusting us with your finance and we promise to give you the best banking experience as we are renowned.

Regards,
Mrs Sandra Quintana,
Account relationship manager,
Stand Crest Bank.

I did not deposit the $2,000 as they requested. Then I logged in and all the account information looked legitimate.

Then, after a couple of days the money was wired into the account I set up at the bank.

After a couple of days I decided to test it with a couple of wire transfers into my US accounts.

Then after a few days... nothing. I contacted the bank again an received this email reply:

Hello Mr. Frederick,
   We write to notify you that we have successfully enrolled you into the Bank authentication system, and we are awaiting grant/approval as the international financial regulations through the central bank imposed a stamp duty and tax clearance charges of $5,400 usd on the fund being received into your local account as an electronic transfer. This order was contained in a circular to all international transfers made/received.

The central bank states, "As part of efforts to boost it's revenue base, the financial regulations is exploring revenue opportunities especially in taxes and stamp duty charges is in recognition of this fact that banks  and financial institutions are enjoined to support government's revenue drive through compliance with the provision of the Stamp Duty Act once payment is made your fund will be made available in the recipient account within 24 hours as this is the reason you haven't received the fund you transferred, and no difficulties will be met from your bank or any financial institution" .

We await your payment , as we will provide account details for payment upon request.

Regards,
Mr Chris Delgado,
Branch accounting division manager,
Stand Crest Bank

I questioned this, and to why the "fees" couldn't come out of my account. 
I then received this email reply:

Hello Mr. Frederick,
   We write to notify you that we have successfully enrolled you into the Bank authentication system, and we are awaiting grant/approval as the international financial regulations through the central bank imposed a stamp duty and tax clearance charges of $5,400 usd on the fund being received into your local account as an electronic transfer. This order was contained in a circular to all international transfers made/received.

The central bank states, "As part of efforts to boost it's revenue base, the financial regulations is exploring revenue opportunities especially in taxes and stamp duty charges is in recognition of this fact that banks  and financial institutions are enjoined to support government's revenue drive through compliance with the provision of the Stamp Duty Act once payment is made your fund will be made available in the recipient account within 24 hours as this is the reason you haven't received the fund you transferred, and no difficulties will be met from your bank or any financial institution" .

We await your payment , as we will provide account details for payment upon request.

Regards,
Mr Chris Delgado,
Branch accounting division manager,
Stand Crest Bank.

I didn't pay the $5,400.

I have replied back saying that I don't have the $5,400 to see what reply I receive next.

Meanwhile my Marine gal in Syria contacted me asking what was happening on the wiring of funds. I explained what was going on. She said she would take care of it.  Shortly, she came back saying it is okay to deposit the $5,400, as they will wire the funds you requested in 24 hours, which is what they said.  I told her I wanted to do some further research into this first.  The comes the line... don't you trust me?  I said it's not a matter of trusting you, I want to research the bank more.  She finally said...okay.

If this is a scam, it's a very elaborate one.

Comment: 100% this is a scam. No money exists for you to claim. Any money of your own which you move into the account will be lost. Any personal identifying information (PII) which you've given to the "bank" is now in the hands of the scammers. While there might have been some doubt as to if your "Marine gal in Syria" was part of the scam, or just someone who had been taken in by the scam, the fact that the person said "don't you trust me?" makes it highly likely that they are part of the scam.

Comment: BTW: You haven't actually asked a question here. You've just told the story of how you've gotten to the point you're currently at. Without you actually asking a question, it's impossible to provide an answer.